# Cron logs show activity, but app logs show nothing

Tags: centos, cron, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I'm trying to run a daily cron app.

What I did:

```
crontab -e
```

Inside file, I have:

```
0 0 * * * cd /home/ec2-user/myapp && docker-compose up
```

when I check `/var/log/cron`, I get:

```
Jul 29 00:00:01 localhost CROND[28549]: (ec2-user) CMD (cd /home/ec2-user/myapp &&  docker-compose up)
```

But I have no logs in myapp, and I can tell app has not run.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Try including the full path to `docker-compose` instead of just the name.

Comment: it worked, you can put it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-compose` can not be found in cron users `PATH` variable, and therefore can not be run.

One way to fix this is to provide the complete path to the binary.

```
0 0 * * * cd /home/ec2-user/myapp && /usr/local/bin/docker-compose up
```